# JQuery - grab parent of event-object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I bound a function as a closure to an anchor like this:

```
jQuery('#mydiv').find('#mya').bind('click', function(e){
    myotherfunction(e);
});
```

In my function `myotherfunction(obj)`, `obj` is an event, how do I get the parent-Element?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With this:

```
jQuery(obj.target).parent();
```

You might want to refactor your code to this:

```
jQuery('#mya').bind('click', function(e){
    myotherfunction(e.target);
});

function myotherfunction(obj){
    var $parent = jQuery(obj).parent();
    ...
    ...
}
```

**Best practices:**

- `obj` is a bad name for the event variable.
- `id` should be unique so you can search by it only:
  `jQuery('#mydiv').find('#mya')` => `jQuery('#mya')`

Comment: Thanks a lot, especially for your best practice-statements. Those are a great help for my growth as a JQuery-User.